# Use Gmail in Google Chrome for mailto links in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, gmail, mailto

When I log into Gmail for the first time in Chrome on my Windows 8 computer, Chrome asks if I want to use Gmail for `mailto` links.  When I click yes, Windows pops up a dialog to "Choose a program to use for `mailto` links," with the only option being "Look in the Windows Store."

When I go to the "Default Programs" => "Set Associations" window, there is no entry for `mailto`.

How can I set Gmail as the handler for `mailto` links in Windows 8?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is in the following three steps.

1. Set Google Chrome as the handler for `mailto` links.  To do this, go to "Default Programs" in the Windows Control Panel and click "Set your default programs".  Then click "Google Chrome" and click "Choose defaults for this program."  Check the box next to "MAILTO" and click "Save."
2. In Chrome, go to the Gmail website. On the right side you may see an icon [image: Handler icon], representing the handler options:  Click on this icon and allow Google Mail to register as a mail handler. If no icon is available, it means that you have already allowed Google Mail to register its handler and you can skip to step 3.
3. In Chrome, click the menu button and choose "Settings."  Click "Show advanced settings" and then click "Content Settings."  Scroll down and click "Manage handlers."  Select "Gmail" in the dropdown box, then close the settings windows.

Comment: Nov 2017 This seems not to be current anymore in Chrome 62.  When you go into Handlers it simply has one option of "Let programs ask to be handlers"

Answer (score 0):

For inbox and chrome users, just open inbox and you'll see the handler icon

[image]